# Copy store and website configs to a new store programatically

Tags: core-config-data

I know that I can do this with just using SQL.. but I´m looking to learn new ways here ;)

So the scenario is that I have create a new store and want to copy all core/store and core/website settings.

This is my starting point:

```
$oldSiteId = 2;
$newSiteId = 3;

/* Get config from old site */
$oldSiteConfig = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
  ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('config_id',$oldSiteId);


/* Save config to new site */
Mage::getModel('core/config')
  ->saveConfig($newSiteId, $oldSiteConfig);
```

Now this is not working but you get the idea of my approach.. Would love to get some help so I can get it to work!

Comment: 2 and 3 are website ids or store view ids?

Comment: well.. actually they are both :P store and website have the same id in my db

Comment: I want all core_config_data where scope_id = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (untested code so backup before)

```
$newWebsiteId = 3;
$oldWebsiteId = 2;  

$configs = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'websites')
    ->addFieldToFilter('scope_id', $oldWebsiteId);

foreach ($configs as $config)  {
    $newConfig = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');
    $newConfig->setValue($config->getValue())
              ->setPath($config->getPath())
              ->setScope($config->getScope())
              ->setScopeId($newWebsiteId)
              ->save();
}
```

I know this involves `save` in a loop but it should not be a problem since you are probably going to run this script only once.

the code above works for websites.
For store ids just change the line `->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'websites')` to `->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'stores')`

Comment: Like I said in the post.. looking for NEW ways to do this.. NOT thru SQL

Comment: Sorry. I missed that line.

Comment: @Mackelito. Is it better now?

Comment: Now we´re talking.. But I guess I should specify the new store id somewhere!

Comment: Would it work to use "->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'stores')" and "->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'websites')" ?

Comment: Oups. got carried away with it. You should use the new website id for `setScopeId`.

Comment: It´s working.. but not with both "websites" and "stores".. need to do them as separate tasks I guess :) Thx for your help!